# How to test the Availability of http and https servers in java

Tags: java, http, tomcat, https

I need a solution for testing the availability of http and https servers.
For example: I need to know if servers (apache and tomcat) are available or not.

I don't need to consume inputstream, just display a green button if it works or red if it doesn't.

Comment: Make a http connection, check if the status is 200, and make a green boutton?

Answer (score 1):

You can use URLConnection to check that your server is up. More about it:

[Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/using-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

Or HttpsUrlConnection:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-https-client-httpsurlconnection-example/

If connection return 200, then server is working.